# Modify xml nodes using DOM or SIMPLE XML?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have source XML here: http://www.grilykrby.cz/rss/pf-heureka.xml. I want to use this xml feed and create another modified on my own server. I would like to change every node CATEGORYTEXT which contains word Prislusenstvi. I just tried something but I got only the listing of all categories without changing XML :-(
**Here is the example of my code.** The row $kategorie="nejaka kategorie"; doesn't work.

```
<?php
$file = "http://www.grilykrby.cz/rss/pf-heureka.xml";
$xml=simplexml_load_file($file);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//SHOPITEM/CATEGORYTEXT') as $kategorie) {
echo $kategorie."<br />";
$kategorie="nejaka kategorie";
}
file_put_contents('test.xml', $xml->asXML()); 
?>
```

Comment: You should think about using something like XSLT, which is made for manipulating XML documents. Your Problem would probably become trivial with XSLT. Also, you can use it from PHP since PHP comes with a XSLT processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$kategorie` is just a temp variable used in the loop which contains a copy of the data returned by xpath query.  You would need to actually set the value directly in the `$xml` object.

I would personally also consider doing a `str_replace` or `preg_replace` within the XML content itself before parsing it into a simpleXML object.

**Final Accepted Answer**

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.grilykrby.cz/rss/pf-heureka.xml');
$i=0;
foreach($xml -> SHOPITEM as $polozka) {
    if ($polozka -> CATEGORYTEXT == "Příslušenství") $xml -> SHOPITEM[$i] -> CATEGORYTEXT = "Some other text";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Everything, what I am trying, will replace only the first categorytext in first shopitem :-(

Comment: You would need to grab the key, to know which array element to modify try `foreach ($xml->xpath('//SHOPITEM/CATEGORYTEXT') as $key => $kategorie) {`  Then set like `$xml->SHOPITEM->CATEGORYTEXT[$key] = 'nejaka kategorie'` or whatever the correct accessor to that item would be based on your XML structure. If you include a var_dump of your `$xml` structure in your original question it would help a lot to tell you how to access the nodes you are looking for.

Comment: I would like to modify all the categorytext, which contains word "Prislusenstvi" to something else. Can you help me? :)

Comment: Please read my last comment.  You need to make sure that you are accessing the correct object property or array member (again hard to give exact instruction without knowledge about the structure of `$xml`) otherwise you will just be overwriting the same thing over and over again..

Comment: [link](http://vyvoj.nejmag.cz/test/generuj-feed.php) this is the list of categorytext so I think I am accessing the correct object or no?

Comment: I don't know.  That still does nothing to help my understand the structure of the `$xml` object in question (like say adding a var_dump of the object - or pertinent sample part of object if really large - to the original question would.)

Comment: `<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.grilykrby.cz/rss/pf-heureka.xml');
$i=0;
foreach($xml -> SHOPITEM as $polozka){
 if ($polozka -> CATEGORYTEXT == "Příslušenství")
 $xml -> SHOPITEM[$i] -> CATEGORYTEXT = "Some other text";
 $i++;
}

echo $xml -> asXML('test.xml');
?>`
This works fine! thanks!